# Einstein' Summation convention

Tags: tensors

How to write the equation below by Einstein's summation convention?

***dφ=(∂φ/∂x^1)∂x^1+(∂φ/∂x²)∂x²+...+(∂φ/∂xⁿ)∂xⁿ***/

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As written, this does not make sense, I think if you are looking for an answer in Einstein's summation convention, you need to write this as $$\mathrm{d} \varphi  = \left( \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x^{1}}\right) \mathrm{d} x^{1} + \ldots$$

Comment: Try writing it as $\mathrm d\phi=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i}\mathrm dx^i$? This makes more sense than $\partial x^i$ as is in the equation you show.